# How to tell at runtime whether an android app is running through a Alpha , Beta and playstore

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to detect at runtime that an application has been installed through Beta (submitted through play store) vs the Play Store? You can submit a single app bundle and have it available through both. Is there an API that can detect which way it was installed? Or does the receipt contain information that allows this to be determined?

Comment: you can make a flag in your code using sharedPref or sqlite if your app using database

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira : no database . any other way , if possible share link

Comment: javascript localstorage can do the job too

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira can you please share the sample code of that